# my model was redirecting to default page why?

Tags: angularjs, dialog, ng-dialog

I am using `ng-dialog` in my angular project. When I click on element the dialog loading perfectly but at the same time background page and url changing to homepage.

How to keep the page same before and after dialog box.

Here is my js and html

```
$scope.showAssumptions = function () {
  ngDialog.open({ template: '/templates/Assumptions.html' });       
};

<div class="bluetxt">
  <strong><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="assumptions" class="user2" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="showAssumptions()">Assumptions</a></strong> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is fine, but your HTML code must be like: (you don't need this : data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" )

```
 <div class="bluetxt">
  <strong><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="assumptions" class="user2" role="button" ng-click="showAssumptions()">Assumptions</a></strong> 
</div>
```